# NodeJs - Sequelize - Unrecognized datatype for attribute

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make a model for my dcauser table. I get stuck because it returns an error 'Unrecognized datatype for attribute'. Now i don't know if i messed something up in the database or is sequelize not working correctly with my DB or did i mess something up in the code below. I followed some guides but i get always stuck on the same problem i mentioned above.

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://postgres:xpwdx@localhost:xportx/xdbx');


const UserSchema = sequelize.define(
    'dcauser',
    {
        userid: {
            type: Sequelize.Integer,
            allowNull: false,
        }
    }
);


module.exports = UserSchema;
```

i get the following error:

```
C:\Users\luka\source\repos\dcaBotManager\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1005
        throw new Error(`Unrecognized datatype for attribute "${this.name}.${name}"`);
        ^

Error: Unrecognized datatype for attribute "dcauser.userid"
    at C:\Users\luka\source\repos\dcaBotManager\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1005:15
    at C:\Users\luka\source\repos\dcaBotManager\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:13401:38
    at C:\Users\luka\source\repos\dcaBotManager\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4905:15
    at baseForOwn (C:\Users\luka\source\repos\dcaBotManager\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:2990:24)
    at Function.mapValues (C:\Users\luka\source\repos\dcaBotManager\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:13400:7)
    at Function.init (C:\Users\luka\source\repos\dcaBotManager\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1001:28)
    at Sequelize.define (C:\Users\luka\source\repos\dcaBotManager\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:428:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\luka\source\repos\dcaBotManager\src\models\user.model.js:14:30)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\luka\source\repos\dcaBotManager\src\models\index.js:2:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\luka\source\repos\dcaBotManager\src\config\passport.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `integer` keyword must be in uppercase

```
{
    userid: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my issue!:)

Answer (score 1):

INTEGER must be in uppercase. See

https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/data-types.html

Though you should start using DataTypes.INTEGER instead.

https://sequelize.org/master/variable/index.html#static-variable-DataTypes

Comment: Thank you. It fixed my issue:).